# In Symfony, how can I require http in a dev environment and https in production?

Tags: symfony, url-routing

In production, I have a group of routes that require SSL however this shouldn't be a requirement for development.

I thought that I could simply override my routes in `routing_dev.yml` but that doesn't seem to work. When navigating to any route, it forces https.

My Setup:

- **app/config/routing_dev.yml** contains a series of routes, duplicated from src/FOO/FOOBarBundle/Resources/config/routing, without `schemes: [https]`
- **src/FOO/FOOBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml** contains the same as above just with `schemes: [https]`

I expected that the routes in `routing_dev.yml` would have preceded those in the bundle and would have been the ones used while in development.

Am I on the right path, or is there a better way of accomplishing http in development and https in production for a select group of routes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force https for prod but http for dev environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224151/how-to-force-https-for-prod-but-http-for-dev-environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **src/FOO/FOOBarBundle/Resources/config/routing_dev.yml** for dev-environment (import it in **app/config/routing_dev.yml** instead of importing **src/FOO/FOOBarBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**)

Comment: This helped. Thank you. I first duplicated all `FooBarBundle` routes as `src/FOO/FOOBarBundle/Resources/config/routing_dev.yml`, but was able to simplify it further at the top level: in `app/config/routing.yml` I added `schemes: [https]` after the external route YML was included. In `app/config/routing_dev.yml` I added a duplicate entry with an explicit `schemes: [http]`. Thanks!