# How to force https for prod but http for dev environment?

Tags: php, symfony, https, routes

I have a symfony2 application.

On the prod server I want all my routes to go via https, while in dev I want to be able to use http. How do I achieve that with symfony2 alone? I do not want to touch the webserver configuration.

I tried adding this in my `routing.yml`

```
myBundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    schemes:  [https]
```

while having this in my `routing_dev.yml`:

```
myBundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    schemes:  [http]

_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

It still wants to go to https even in dev mode.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Symfony, how can I require http in a dev environment and https in production?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971030/in-symfony-how-can-i-require-http-in-a-dev-environment-and-https-in-production)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can define parameter for that. In `app/config/config.yml` define:

```
parameters:
    httpProtocol: http
```

Then in `app/config/config_prod.yml`:

```
parameters:
    httpProtocol: https
```

And in `routing.yml` change to:

```
myBundle:
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
    schemes:  ['%httpProtocol%']
```

Clear the cache (both prod and dev) and it should work.

Comment: That's such a good idea! It also works for configuring `security.yml`.

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this case-by-case in an annotation, this is the way:

@Route("/register.html", schemes={"%httpProtocol%"})

Comment: It's worth noting that you'd need to add the schemes setting to fos_user routing as well if you're employing that too.

Answer (score 2):

Change your app.php last lines like this:

```
if ($request->getScheme() === 'http') {
    $urlRedirect = str_replace($request->getScheme(), 'https', $request->getUri());
    $response = new RedirectResponse($urlRedirect);
} else {
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);
}

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: I would not want to hardcode the schema in `app.php `, I prefer to have such setting in configuration files to easily change the settings.

Comment: You have not any configuration file before http kernel ran!

Comment: This is not entirely true. Please look at the accepted answer and at the answer how I got it working for me. No changes to the `app.php` were necessary there. You provided a working solution, yet none that I would recommend.

Answer (score 1):

My first solution works fine, yet one should take care to not overwrite one own's routes in the `routing_dev.yml`. At the end of the file, I had

```
_main:
    resource: routing.yml
```

so all my bundle route was changed back to the https-scheme. Ordering the entries, so that my custom entry comes last resolved the issue.

Comment: I tried setting `schemes: [https]` in my app/config/routing.yml under `resource: "@MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"` but it does not work (it does not enforce HTTPS for the routes defined in my bundle). Have you tried doing something like you propose in routes not using the `type: annotation`?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can check the scheme in `app_dev.php` file and base on that redirect it to https

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if ($url['scheme'] == 'http') {
   header("Location: https://{$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}");
}
```

Or maybe able to apply some changes in `.htaccess` for `app_dev.php` in URL

Comment: Alas this is not possible, as on prod, the http port is blocked, so I cannot do any redirect from there and is also the reason why I do not want to depend on serverside config but achieve it within symfony2 config.

Comment: I thought you just want to do that for dev mode and the prod can use both http and https

Comment: If the http port is blocked, how would the request even reach apache, let alone symfony